# Create a tree with cakephp

Tags: php, cakephp, tree, crud, directory

I'd like to create a tree with real folders in my webroot/files, so I tried some functions like tree() to retrieve them but I don't know how to use this.
I'd like to navigate into those folders too, and doing some CRUD actions on them.

edit : Can't I avoid database connexion to retrieve my folders ?

Anyone got an idea?

Answer (score 0):

get the values from your database and implement using dynatree  jquery plugin of google. see [here](http://code.google.com/p/dynatree/). is this what you are looking for.